# how to mix between columns and rows in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to two add two containers next to each other in a row with two icon buttons on the bottom of the app like shown in the picture. i tried to use sizedbox but it wasn't enough. [image]

i started the code with this but couldn't continue:

```
class Restaurent extends StatefulWidget {
  const Restaurent({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _Restaurent createState() => _Restaurent();
}

class _Restaurent extends State<Restaurent> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Restaurant") ,
      ),

      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.youtube_searched_for),
          ]
          ),
          ),
      ),
      
    );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Row()` with setting `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end`.
Here's an example, you can adjust it to fit what you want:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Text("hi"),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Text("hi"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          Divider(
            thickness: 5,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Text("hi"),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Text("hi"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Result:

[image]